# SQL - Poor Performance SELECT Query on 377 million table

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, bigdata

I got a table with the following structure:

```
Id | clientid | type | timeStamp | message |
```

I'm using this query to get the first rows of table to start deleting rows but is crashing the DB:

```
SELECT TOP 10 [id]
      ,[clientid]
      ,[type]
      ,[timeStamp]
      ,[message]
FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
WHERE timeStamp LIKE '%2014-01-01 00:00:00.000%'
```

Is there any way to get the first rows without crashing and delete them before arrive to `timeStamp` `'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000'`?

Comment: What is your logic behind `WHERE timeStamp LIKE '%2014-01-01 00:00:00.000%'`?

Comment: I was trying to get the first rows, I was thinking of looking by dates but this is not the solution. @Matt

Comment: Is your timestamp a DATETIME column and is there an index on this column?

Comment: Its DATETIME but is not Indexed. @Shnugo

Comment: You should set an index on this column probably...

Comment: Please give details on *crashes my DB*... What does this mean exeactly?

Comment: Website go down and SQL Server freeze. @Shnugo

Comment: You need to increase timeout for sql request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly:

If you set an index on your TimeStamp column it should be absolutely fast to filter rows greater or smaller a given date.

These lines will delete everything from your table where the TimeStamp is smaller than 2016-01-01. Only current entries will remain...

#### Attention: Be careful! Don't test against real data! :-)

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID 
            FROM myTable AS innerTbl 
            WHERE innerTbl.Timestamp<{ts'2016-01-01 00:00:00'}
           )
```

#### Update

This will delete 1000 rows per call. The number behind "GO" will execute this snippet 377000 times. Test with smaller numbers...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE ID IN(SELECT TOP 1000
            ID 
            FROM myTable AS innerTbl 
            WHERE innerTbl.Timestamp<{ts'2016-01-01 00:00:00'}
           );
COMMIT;
GO 377000
```

Comment: Im with a problem.. I only got 9 GB of free space in Disc. So I can't back up tables and I have to start deleting old rows to gain space. It will crash If I index the 377 million rows?

Comment: @devtreat The index will need about ~ 3 GB and such a heavy delete operation will blow up the transaction log... I'd suggest to create the index and delete in portions (each transaction committed). I'll edit my answer soon...

Comment: This query will decrease the DISC space? GO 377000 throw me error "Could not find stored procedure '', "Incorrect syntax near '377000'"

Comment: @devtreat, Once the rows are deleted (and maybe several times while you are deleting your rows, you should shrink your DB. Read about [DBCC SHRINKDATABASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190488.aspx)

Comment: @devtreat How are you calling this? The "GO" is not even a SQL command, just a *end-of-batch* sign in SSMS. It is even possible to change this. The error you recieve let's me think, that you do not execute this from SSMS, do you?

Comment: Yes, I was executing this on SSMS. Without )BEGIN TRANSACTION; COMMIT; GO 377000) Its working fine, but I need to do it automatically.

Comment: @devtreat Strange... What happens if you just type `SELECT GETDATE();GO` **The GO must sit in its own line!!!**? What about `SELECT GETDATE();GO 2`? [Read about GO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) Is this a *one-time-shot*?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112141/discussion-between-devtreat-and-shnugo).

Answer (score 1):

Simple?

```
WHERE timeStamp = '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: This crash my DB too :/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `LIKE` ? This is most defiently slows down your query, `LIKE` is usually used to compare partially string.

You can just trunc the date time, and use normal comparison :

```
SELECT TOP 10 [id]
      ,[clientid]
      ,[type]
      ,[timeStamp]
      ,[message]
FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
WHERE cast(timeStamp AS DATE) = '2014-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why your using `LIKE` when there is nothing extra that can be added to the datetime.

Either use `=`.

```
SELECT TOP 10 [id]
      ,[clientid]
      ,[type]
      ,[timeStamp]
      ,[message]
FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
WHERE timeStamp ='2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Or if your trying to get all from that day use the `CONVERT` function. (I chose `103` as i see your from Spain and use the `DD/MM/YYYY` format).

```
SELECT TOP 10 [id]
      ,[clientid]
      ,[type]
      ,[timeStamp]
      ,[message]
FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),timeStamp ,103) = '01/01/2014'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess ID is an identity column? probably the lazy DBA has left it as a clustered index too? just do

```
DELETE TOP (10) from [Table] order by ID ASC
```

Be warned though in Full logging mode this is going to be intense

Answer (score 0):

You should create an index on timestamp.

You could setup a filtered index, since it's a fairly big table.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table_timestamp ON Table([timestamp]) WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[timestamp]) = '2014-01-01';
```

And then delete rows by small batches.

> Code from an older post from [Aaron Bertrand](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @r INT;

SET @r = 1;

WHILE @r > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  DELETE TOP (10000) 
    dbo.Table
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE,[timestamp]) = '2014-01-01';

  SET @r = @@ROWCOUNT;

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an auto incremented column ID than why you are selecting first row using ID?

```
DELETE TOP (1) from [Table] order by ID ASC
```